# How can I import a module into powershell without waiting for it to complete?

Tags: powershell, module, powershell-3.0, import-module

I have a psm1 file I want to load into my $profile, but it takes long to load. I would prefer to load it "in the background" where it doesn't prevent immediate action in my powershell prompt. If I run it as a job, I don't get the functions from the psm1 file. Any ideas how I can do this? It doesn't look like there are any flags to "load in the background" from Import-Module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell jobs are run in their own session. I imagine that importing the module is working fine, but just not in the PowerShell session you want.
See [about_Job_Details](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847853.aspx)

Why does your module take so long to load? Maybe you can improve that?

Comment: The psm1 loads a bunch of other modules (probably 50-70). I don't care if they are immediately available, but I would want to have them eventually

Comment: @EGr. Rather than loading them at startup in your profile, you could just define (in your profile) an easily remembered helper function to load them when you want them. Only take the hit when you actually need it, rather than every time you start PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell v3 and newer provide automatic loading of modules in `$env:PSModulePath` as soon as one of the module members is called, so there shouldn't be any need for you to import a module in your profile.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for my use-case. I added the network path where the psm1 is located; but it doesn't seem to load them.

Comment: It probably won't work with a network path; I imagine it would have to be stored locally.

Comment: @briantist Probably. Execution policy might also have an impact.